# `-costToNode:` Not Sent to GKGraphNode2D Subclass in GameplayKit

Tags: ios, gameplay-kit

I have what is perhaps a stupid question about Apple's new GameplayKit.

I am creating a 2D grid-based node layout for my game. I mostly love the functionality of the `GKGraphNode2D`, but would like to tweak it in one way. I'd like to conditionally add a penalty when traversing a certain kind of node pair. In other words, I want some nodes connected in a straight-forward way, and some nodes connected such that their traversal distance is modified by my app.

I thought subclassing `GKGraphNode2D` and overriding `-costToNode:` and `-estimatedCostToNode:` would work perfectly! I'd return the value supplied by `super` sometimes, and tweak it for my game at other times. These two methods are methods on `GKGraphNode`, the superclass of `GKGraphdNode2D`.

Unfortunately, when I try to do this, it appears that `-costToNode:` and `-estimatedCostToNode:` are never called on my `GKGraphNode2D` subclass. I would expect these methods to be invoked when I call `-findPathFromNode:toNode:` on my `GKGraph` object that contains a bunch of my `GKGraphNode2D` subclass objects.

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit:

The following is my code.

Create two classes, `CheapNode` and `ExpensiveNode`, that are subclasses of `GKGraphNode2D`, as follows:

```
@import UIKit;
@import GameplayKit;

@interface CheapNode : GKGraphNode2D
@end

@implementation CheapNode

- (float)estimatedCostToNode:(GKGraphNode *)node {
    return 1;
}

- (float)costToNode:(GKGraphNode *)node {
    return 1;
}

@end
```

and

```
@import UIKit;
@import GameplayKit;

@interface ExpensiveNode : GKGraphNode2D
@end

@implementation ExpensiveNode

- (float)estimatedCostToNode:(GKGraphNode *)node {
    return 100;
}

- (float)costToNode:(GKGraphNode *)node {
    return 100;
}

@end
```

Then in a test, I've created some nodes, connected them, added them to a graph, and sent the `findPathFromNode:toNode:` message to the graph. Then, I check the path that the graph finds, and I don't find what I expect.

```
- (void)testNodeCostsUsed {
    /*
     This is the graph we are creating:

     A---B---C
     |       |
     F---E---D

     where all of the nodes are `CheapNode` objects, except 'B', which is an
     `ExpensiveNode` object.

     This test finds a path from node A to node C.

     If the cost methods in the `CheapNode` and `ExpensiveNode` subclasses
     are used, the route going from A to C around B (down, then right, then up)
     should be used, since the cost of going from B to C is 100, and the cost of
     going from any other node to any other node is 1 
     (see implementation of these classes).

     Instead, we see `GKGraph` choosing the "shortest" route in terms of number
     of nodes, from the top left immediately to the right to the top right.
     */

    CheapNode     *nodeA = [[CheapNode alloc]     initWithPoint:(vector_float2){0, 0}];
    ExpensiveNode *nodeB = [[ExpensiveNode alloc] initWithPoint:(vector_float2){1, 0}];
    CheapNode     *nodeC = [[CheapNode alloc]     initWithPoint:(vector_float2){2, 0}];
    CheapNode     *nodeD = [[CheapNode alloc]     initWithPoint:(vector_float2){2, 1}];
    CheapNode     *nodeE = [[CheapNode alloc]     initWithPoint:(vector_float2){1, 1}];
    CheapNode     *nodeF = [[CheapNode alloc]     initWithPoint:(vector_float2){0, 1}];

    [nodeA addConnectionsToNodes:@[ nodeB, nodeF ] bidirectional:YES];
    [nodeC addConnectionsToNodes:@[ nodeB, nodeD ] bidirectional:YES];
    [nodeE addConnectionsToNodes:@[ nodeF, nodeD ] bidirectional:YES];

    NSArray *allNodes = @[ nodeA, nodeB, nodeC, nodeD, nodeE, nodeF ];

    GKGraph *graph = [GKGraph graphWithNodes:allNodes];
    NSArray *nodes = [graph findPathFromNode:nodeA toNode:nodeC];

    NSArray *expectedPath   = @[ nodeA, nodeF, nodeE, nodeD, nodeC ];
    NSArray *prohibitedPath = @[ nodeA, nodeB, nodeC ];

    XCTAssert([nodes isEqualToArray:expectedPath], @"");
    XCTAssertFalse([nodes isEqualToArray:prohibitedPath], @"");
}
```

This test case fails. I also notice that `estimatedCostToNode:` and `costToNode:` are never sent to my `GKGraphNode2D` subclasses (as verified by log statements and breakpoints).

[Here](https://github.com/timcamber/GKGraphNode2D-Subclass-Bug) is a sample project demonstrating this issue. It should build and run on the latest developer beta of Xcode (as of 08/31/2015, Xcode beta 6).

## Edit 2:

I have submitted the sample code and the description in this StackOverflow question as a bug (http://www.openradar.me/22524760) if anyone is interested in duping. If the bug persists after iOS 9 is released, I will use a developer support ticket to try to resolve this issue.

## Edit 3:

Apple got back to me on my Developer Support Ticket. They admitted this is a bug, and it (as far as I can tell) seems to be fixed in iOS 9.2 beta 2 (7C46t).

## Edit 4:

I have updated the [sample project](https://github.com/timcamber/GKGraphNode2D-Subclass-Bug) to illustrate another [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934409/gkgraph-incorrectly-calculates-path-with-gkgraphnode2d-subclassed-nodes) with this framework.

Comment: Well, the one thing you're obviously doing wrong is not posting your code so that someone could check it for any (more or less obvious) issues. ;) I can only tell you that this is the correct way to go about it, and that it works for me (grid graph).

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I've asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317628/subclass-of-gkgraphnode-costtonode-method-never-getting-called including the code that I am using

Comment: @LearnCocos2D sample code posted!

Comment: Do you have any updates? I am interested in this too.

Comment: Sadly still have not heard back from my dev tech support ticket

Comment: @Weston check latest edit to question, this bug should be fixed in 9.2 beta 2

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was in the process of rolling my own. If you can test in 9.2 and post an answer, I will close my question and mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @Weston an answer involves simply running the test suite in my [test project](https://github.com/timcamber/GKGraphNode2D-Subclass-Bug) on 9.2 beta 2. The tests pass, so I consider this resolved in that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple responded to my developer support ticket related to this issue and told me it was a known issue, and that there was a potential fix in the iOS SDK 9.2 beta 2, released November 3, 2015. I verified that the tests in my [test project](https://github.com/timcamber/GKGraphNode2D-Subclass-Bug) pass in 9.2b2, and so I expect that version to resolve this issue.

Comment: I tested as well, this is confirmed https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5819r51x7yiiaa/MapTest1.mov?dl=0