# GameplayKit: Stop Pathfinding When Path Is Blocked By Certain Obstacles

Tags: ios, scenekit, gameplay-kit

I have a SceneKit project into which I'm trying to integrate GameplayKit's *2D* pathfinding capabilities.

What I have are 2 different kinds of obstacles (let's call them "good obstacles" and "bad obstacles"). The main character can touch the good ones, but not the bad ones (or it's level failed).

**What I need GameplayKit to do if there's a "bad obstacle" in the way of the path is to *stop pathfinding and notify me that the process failed*.**

How might I accomplish this?

Here's some code to illustrate that I do have pathfinding working -- minus the desired behavior, of course:

```
var obstacles = [GKPolygonObstacle]()

//Manually plot a set of points around the circumference of a circle...
//...for use in creating the obstacle (because I was unable to get `GKCircleObstacle` working)
let pegRadius: Float = 0.15
let numOfPoints = 12
let totalRadians: Float = 360.0 * .pi / 180.0
let radiansPerPoint: Float = totalRadians / Float(numOfPoints)
var polyPoints = [SIMD2<Float>]()
for i in 0..<numOfPoints {
   let angle = radiansPerPoint * Float(i)
   let x = pegPosition.x + (pegRadius * cos(angle))
   let y = pegPosition.y + (pegRadius * sin(angle))
         
   polyPoints.append(SIMD2(x: x, y: y))
}

//Create the obstacle:
let obstacle = GKPolygonObstacle(points: polyPoints)

obstacles.append(obstacle)


let graph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: obstacles, bufferRadius: 0.05)

//Grab the nodes that will act as "to" and "from":
let receptors = scnView.scene?.rootNode.childNodes(passingTest: { theNode, stop in
     return theNode.name == "receptors"
}) as? [SCNNodeIdentifiable]
var receptorIndex: Int = 0
guard let receptors = receptors else {
     return
}
    
                
var startPointVector = vector_float2(x: Float(receptors[receptorIndex].presentation.worldPosition.x), y: Float(receptors[receptorIndex].presentation.worldPosition.y))
let endPointVector = vector_float2(x: Float(receptors[receptorIndex+1].presentation.worldPosition.x), y: Float(receptors[receptorIndex+1].presentation.worldPosition.y))
var startingPoint = GKGraphNode2D(point: startPointVector)
let endPoint = GKGraphNode2D(point: endPointVector)

graph.connectUsingObstacles(node: startingPoint)
graph.connectUsingObstacles(node: endPoint)
var path = (graph as GKGraph).findPath(from: startingPoint, to: endPoint)
                
if path.count >= 2 {
   //Path found! Do something.
} else {
   //I'd like to end up here if there's a "bad obstacle" in the way of the pathfinding
}
```

I suspect that the answer has to do with `GKRule` and `GKRuleSystem`, but I could use some input.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, according to the documentation, the correct way to handle this is to subclass `GKGraphNode2D` and override the `cost(to:)` method, which the `findPath` methods use in constructing a path through the graph.

On `cost(to:)`, the docs say the following:

> "Subclasses can implement this method to add other information to the
> cost. For example, a game might use higher costs to represent travel
> through regions of a map that are difficult for a character to
> traverse."

Unfortunately, it appears that this is totally broken and does not work.

Consider the following attempt at making "bad" obstacles have a higher cost than "good" ones:

```
class MyGraphNode2Dsubclass: GKGraphNode2D {
    var isBadObstacle: Bool = false
    
    override func cost(to node: GKGraphNode) -> Float {
       isBadObstacle ? 10.0 : super.cost(to: node)
    }
    
}
```

When it gets to `super.cost(to: node)`, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash 100% of the time.

Now, what I *can* do is this:

```
class MyGraphNode2Dsubclass: GKGraphNode2D {
    var isBadObstacle: Bool = false
    
    override func cost(to node: GKGraphNode) -> Float {
       isBadObstacle ? 10.0 : 0.1
    }
    
}
```

But that results in all "good" obstacles having the same cost of `0.1` instead of having their true costs, so it's not a good solution.

Obviously, if the *cost* system of GameplayKit doesn't really work, then GameplayKit itself doesn't really work.

There are some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975084/costtonode-not-sent-to-gkgraphnode2d-subclass-in-gameplaykit) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317628/subclass-of-gkgraphnode-costtonode-method-never-getting-called) from years past that *might* involve this same problem -- but I'm not sure. They might be describing something a bit different, but on the same topic.

Of course, it's also possible that I've misunderstood this problem -- so please let me know if that's the case.